# There is a problem in SO, so you can search with tags

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow

When I click on any tag in SO, it return zero results.

**Edit:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152476/why-is-windows-select-not-always-notifying-thread-bs-select-when-thread-a-cl) post for example have the tags: windows, c, select, stdin, multithreading.

When I click on any of the above tags, except c tag, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) page, which is tell me:

> You are on the Featured tab.
>
> There are no Featured questions in the
>   windows tag at the moment.
>
> Perhaps you'd like to select a
>   different tab?

So, now I'm actually reading, and understand what going on..

Comment: No repro. Works on my machine.

Comment: You're being rather cagey with any details.

Comment: @Mendy - Please provide a link (from your browser's address line) where you are seeing this.

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on the "featured" tab?

Notice this text in the body of the page:

> You are on the Featured tab.
>
> There are no Featured questions in the [stackexchange] tag at the moment.
>
> Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Comment: I don't understand why I don't read this message, and decide there is a problem. Maybe the message need to be in a different color?